# Why are these probabilities of hitting on a soft 17 in BlackJack correct?

Tags: probability

These are probabilities submitted by Mike Aponte a senior member of the successful MIT blackjack team.

18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | Bust

Stand Soft 17 | 14.62% | 14.04% | 18.85% | 7.65% | 29.60%

Hit Soft 17 | 14.82% | 14.24% | 19.06% | 7.86% | 30.00%

What I don't understand is why aren't your chances of obtaining 18+ when standing on soft 17 0%? You don't hit so there is no chance you can get above 18?

Comment: an ace counting as 10?

Comment: right so the percentages shown for standing on soft 17 are just percentages of getting 18-21 if he hits under 17?

Comment: yes (but see the answer below: this are probabilities for the dealer depending on whether he has to stand/hit soft 17)

Answer (score 0):

[Below are the dealer outcome probabilities](http://mikeaponte.com/game-selection/hit-soft-17-friend-or-foe/)

These are not probabilities of what will happen when you hit or stand on a soft 17.  They are the dealers probabilities whether the hit or stand rule is in  effect.

I think Aponte is saying when the casino the dealer works in has the stand  soft rule in effect, for ALL hands these are the outcomes, these are not just the outcomes when the dealer has a soft 17.

Note 14.62 + 14.04 + 18.85 + 7.65 + 29.60 = 84.76, so I assume the dealer gets a hard or soft 17 15.24

Comment: So if the stand rule is in effect, there's a 14.62% chance he will get 18, how does that work?

Comment: e.g., the dealer holds J6; hits (because < 17); draws a 2.

Comment: Actually I've never asked a question so I'm not sure.  If you click on the arrow it votes up the answer.